# javascript redirect with amended window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to run a JS redirect to point to an amended pathname but not sure how to remove the first folder. eg

Current URL is - www.siteA.com/blog/articlename/

Redirect location is - blog.siteA.com/articlename/

I'm using:

```
window.location.replace("https://blog.siteA.com" + window.location.pathname) ;
```

which will result in - blog.siteA.com/blog/articlename/

What would the script need to be to remove the /blog/ folder from the current pathname?

The redirect needs to be in javascript

Thanks

Comment: `.replace("blog/", "")` ??

Comment: is this a single url or you have multiple urls like this?

Comment: Please confirm the edits. You forgot to highlight the code.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the last part of the current location that starts with `/` and redirect to that path including the origin:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var newPathname = pathname.slice(pathname.lastIndexOf('/'));
var origin = window.location.origin;

window.location = origin + newPathname;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Its not always the last / - sometimes it also includes a category - eg:
www.siteA.com/blog/category/article/
in which case I need the category folder to remain otherwise the article won't exist on the new subdomain.

Also if it ends in '/' eg /article/ doesn't this mean that the query would apply to that last '/' which in this case is blank?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've got it working using hybrid of the answer give:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
var newPathname = pathname.slice(pathname.lastIndexOf('/blog/')+5);
window.location.replace("https://blog.siteA.com" + newPathname);
```

This should then take into account the categories and top-level sections when there are more than one folder that is needed to be copied across - eg 
https://www.siteA.com/blog/category/article/
As well as redirecting https://www.siteA.com/blog/

Thanks for the help